# Formatting Text in LabelFor() Control

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to format a price label so the price is always in the **0.00 format** and I saw a similar question that used similar code as mine below. I'm getting an `object reference not set to an instance of an object` error and I know that it is because I am calling `Model.Price` but I'm very new to MVC and I don't understand how I set `Model.Price` before the page is loaded.

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price, "0.00", new { id = "priceLabel", Value = String.Format("{0:C}", Model.Price) })
```

Here is the Controller code:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        // set the paper style list
        List<SelectListItem> styles = new List<SelectListItem>();
        ViewBag.paperStyle = new SelectList(styles, "Value", "Text");

        // set the subject list
        List<SelectListItem> subjects = new List<SelectListItem>();
        ViewBag.subject = new SelectList(subjects, "Value", "Text");

        // set the number of pages list
        List<SelectListItem> numberOfPages = new List<SelectListItem>();
        ViewBag.Urgency = new SelectList(urgency, "Value", "Text");

        // set the document type list
        List<SelectListItem> documentTypes = new List<SelectListItem>();
        ViewBag.documentType = new SelectList(documentTypes, "Value", "Text");

        // set the academic level list
        List<SelectListItem> academicLevel = new List<SelectListItem>();
        ViewBag.academicLevel = new SelectList(academicLevel, "Value", "Text");

        // set the number of sources list
        List<SelectListItem> numberOfSources = new List<SelectListItem>();
        ViewBag.numberOfSources = new SelectList(numberOfSources, "Value", "Text");

        // set the currency list
        List<SelectListItem> currencies = new List<SelectListItem>();
        currencies.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "$", Value = "USD", Selected = true });
        currencies.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "£", Value = "GBP", Selected = false });
        currencies.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "€", Value = "EUR", Selected = false });

        ViewBag.currency = new SelectList(currencies, "Value", "Text");

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Contact(WritingAppModel c)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // send the email and process the payment

            // if payment is ready then send email
            if (isPaymentReady())
            {
                // send email

            }
        }
        return View();
    }

public class modelData
    {
        public string documentType { get; set; }
        public string numberOfPages { get; set; }
        public string urgency { get; set; }
    }

    public JsonResult getNewPrice(modelData dropdownValues)
    {
        // check for urgency first since that is the base price
        if (dropdownValues.urgency != null)
        {
            currentPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(dropdownValues.urgency);

            if (dropdownValues.documentType != null)
            {
                currentPrice = currentPrice + Convert.ToDecimal(dropdownValues.documentType);

                if (dropdownValues.numberOfPages != null)
                {
                    currentPrice = currentPrice * Convert.ToInt16(dropdownValues.numberOfPages);
                }
            }
        }

        // do something with value and return a decimal
        return Json(new { currentPrice = currentPrice }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here is the View code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<div class="row">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, "Name:")
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
<div class="row">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, "Email:")
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Email, new { id = "email" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
</div>
<div class="row">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Topic, "Topic:")
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Topic)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Topic)
</div>
<div class="row">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Subject, "Subject:")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Subject, (SelectList)ViewBag.subject, "--Select--", new { id = "subjectList" })
</div>
<div class="row">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Style, "Style:")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Style, (SelectList)ViewBag.paperStyle, "--Select--", new { id = "paperStyleList" })
</div>
<div class="row">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DocumentType, "Document Type:")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DocumentType, (SelectList)ViewBag.documentType, "--Select--", new { id = "documentTypeList" })
</div>
<div class="row">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AcademicLevel, "Academic Level:")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AcademicLevel, (SelectList)ViewBag.academicLevel, "--Select--", new { id = "academicLevelList" })
</div>
<div class="row">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NumberOfPages, "Number of Pages/Words:")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.NumberOfPages, (SelectList)ViewBag.numberOfPages, "--Select--", new { id = "numberOfPagesList" })
</div>
<div class="row">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NumberOfSources, "Number of Sources:")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.NumberOfSources, (SelectList)ViewBag.numberOfSources, "--Select--", new { id = "numberOfSourcesList" })
</div>
<div class="row">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Urgency, "Urgency:")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Urgency, (SelectList)ViewBag.urgency, "--Select--", new { id = "urgencyList" })
</div>
<div class="row">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Spacing, "Spacing:")
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Spacing, "Single") Single
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Spacing, "Double") Double
</div>
<div class="row">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Requirements, "Requirements:")
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Requirements)
</div>
<div class="row">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Currency, (SelectList)ViewBag.currency, null, new { id = "currencyList" })
    <h2>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price, "{0:C}", new { id = "priceLabel" })
    </h2>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</div>
}
```

Comment: Does your model have a `Price` property? and is the model set in the `View`.

Comment: @christiandev First off let me begin by saying that this is my very first MVC project. public decimal Price { get; set; } is what I have it set as in the model so I believe that means it is set correctly as the price property.

Comment: show us the `Controller` and the `View`

Comment: `@LabelFor()` generates the name of the property (or the value generated by `[Display(Name="My Label")]` attribute, not the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the controller looks like, but take this test version...

**Controller**

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new Product {Price = 9.99m};
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

I've created a Product class as an example..

```
 public class Product
    {
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
```

Your `view` will then need to reference the `model`.

```
@model WebApplication2.Controllers.Product

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price, new { id = "priceLabel" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Price, new { id = "priceLabel", 
                              Value = String.Format("{0:C}", Model.Price) })
```

You can see from the controller where the model is built and passed to the view.

```
var model = new Product {Price = 9.99m};
return View(model);
```

The `LabelFor` will generate a label for the actual property, not the value for it.

**EDIT**: Based on comment.

If you only want to display the property...

```
@String.Format("{0:C}", Model.Price)
```

or. as Steve suggested...

**Model**:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)
```

Comment: Note, This is creating 2 elements with the same id (invalid html) and `Value = String.Format("{0:C}", Model.Price)` is not necessary (it can be just `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Price, "{0:C}")`

Comment: I can use the code in the index method because that looks what I need in my code but my code creates a price based on the options that the user chooses will the price stay in memory?

Comment: I'm not understanding why I need to use a textboxfor and a label if all I'm doing is displaying the price. Shouldn't I just need a label and format that?

Comment: I also want to apologize for my long delay in responding. I fell asleep soon after posting this.

Comment: I tried your test code and the textbox value is formatted correctly but what I wanted was just a label to display the price.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I was just showing what both variations did on the page, since I was unsure what the desired result was.

Comment: @user3610374. If you dont want an editable control, just use `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)` and add a`[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:C}")]` attribute to the property

Comment: I used the suggestions in the edit and it looks correct when the page loads but now it isn't changing the price like it used to. My GetNewPrice method is supposed to calculate a price based on the user options and then display that in the priceLabel and it isn't doing that anymore :(

Comment: You can use String Interpolation (part of C# 6.0) in the following manner:

`@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Price, new { Value = $"{Model.Price:C}"})`